# Ionic 3, getting Runtime Error after selecting value from ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build ion-select using FormBuilder. I have not found dynamic ion-select example with FormBuilder. So when I create form using my udnerstanding, I am getting

```
Runtime Error
Error trying to diff 'evaluator.id'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Here is my Component code

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public viewCtrl: ViewController,
            public modalCtrl: ModalController,public formBuilder:FormBuilder) {

      this.fillEvaluators();

      this.cpoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        evaluators:['', Validators.required]
      });
  }
```

and page template goes like thos

```
 <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Evaluator</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]='evaluators' formControlName="evaluators">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let evaluator of evaluators" value="evaluator.id">{{evaluator.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Here evaluators is an array of objects.

```
this.evaluators=[{
      id:2,
      name:"My Test Evaluators"
    }
    .....
}
```

System Info:

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.8
Angular Core: 5.2.7
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.7
Node: 9.4.0
OS Platform: macOS High Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like described on the **[docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/#object-value-references)** from Ionic. Use `[value]`.

Here's a quick example:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Name(s)</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="data.person" multiple>
        <ion-option *ngFor="#name of namesList" [value]="name.shortName" [checked]="false">{{name.shortName}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you. I must be dumb to not to see that.

and Ron, Can't we use [(ngModel)]?
if I add [(ngModel)] it gives runtime error, Error trying to diff '2'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: It can always happen that you overlook something, be sure if it works to mark the answer as a good answer, so other people can find it.